# Speedup split of the string list base on some condition

Tags: python, python-re

I have string list and I need to find elements according some rule.
The find rule is the following - I should find all elements for which there is corresponding domain name. To solve this task I use the following code:

```
import re

pattern = '^<{0,1}([a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.){1,3}[a-z]{2,6}$'

input = ['a.ru','b.ru','cc.com','dd.com','a.ru/11','a.ru/22','cc.com/31231','cc.com/312312412','cc.com/3123141241','cc.com/31231234232','dd.com/11','dd.com/22','dasdas.zz/alpha']

domain_wide = [] # contains domain only
http_urls = []   # contains url's

for line in input:
    if re.match(pattern, line):
        domain_wide.append(line.lower())
    else:
        http_urls.append(line.lower())

domain_wide = tuple(sorted(domain_wide))

#Finding url's for which there is domain in the input data
remove_list = []
for url in http_urls:
    if url.startswith(domain_wide):
        remove_list.append(url)

print(f'The elements should be removed from input data: {remove_list}\n')
print('\n')

final_http_urls = list(set(http_urls) - set(remove_list))
print(f"Elements should be saved in input data: {final_http_urls}")
```

Correct output is:

```
The elements should be removed from input data: ['a.ru/11', 'a.ru/22', 'cc.com/31231', 'cc.com/312312412', 'cc.com/3123141241', 'cc.com/31231234232', 'dd.com/11', 'dd.com/22']
Elements should be saved in input data: ['dasdas.zz/alpha']
```

All work fine - but for big data to slow... My question is how speedup my solution.

**P.S.** Slow part of this solution - *Finding url's for which there is domain in the input data*

Comment: can you elaborate this part ```find all elements for which there is corresponding domain name```?

Comment: I have 400000 strings in input data and find part works 20 minutes

Comment: I meant what do you mean by element with corresponding domain name? Can you provide an example?

Comment: ['a.ru/11', 'a.ru'] - 'a.ru/11' should be exclude from input data(because input data contains corresponding domain name 'a.ru'.
['a.ru/11', 'a.ru', 'b.ru/22']  - with 'b.ru/22' all are Okey

Comment: does input always have domain and urls or, it have other garbage string data as well?

Comment: `p = re.compile(regex)` and `p.match(...)` is extremely performant

Answer (score 1):

The optimized code looks like this

```py
import re

pattern = r'^<{0,1}([a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.){1,3}[a-z]{2,6}$'

urls = ['a.ru', 'b.ru', 'cc.com', 'dd.com', 'a.ru/11', 'a.ru/22', 'cc.com/31231', 'cc.com/312312412',
        'cc.com/3123141241', 'cc.com/31231234232', 'dd.com/11', 'dd.com/22', 'dasdas.zz/alpha']

domains = [url for url in urls if re.match(pattern, url)]

remove_list = [url for domain in domains for url in urls if url.startswith(domain) and url != domain]

final_http_urls = [url for url in urls if url not in (*domains, *remove_list)]

print(f'The elements should be removed from input data: {remove_list}\n\n')
print(f"Elements should be saved in input data: {final_http_urls}")
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
The elements should be removed from input data: ['a.ru/11', 'a.ru/22', 'cc.com/31231', 'cc.com/312312412', 'cc.com/3123141241', 'cc.com/31231234232', 'dd.com/11', 'dd.com/22']
Elements should be saved in input data: ['dasdas.zz/alpha']
```

Comment: It is less code but this is slower than the OP's version.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data doesn't have garbage strings and only contain domains and urls you can use following approach as well.

To verify, the efficiency, you can use `timeit` module and test the run time for all versions you have. During my test, following code ran around 70% faster than your original version. But, I would recommend you test on your own.

```py
input_ = ['a.ru','b.ru','cc.com','dd.com','a.ru/11','a.ru/22','cc.com/31231','cc.com/312312412','cc.com/3123141241','cc.com/31231234232','dd.com/11','dd.com/22','dasdas.zz/alpha']

domain_tracker = set()
final_url = []
remove_list = []
for item in input_:
    if '/' not in item:
        domain_tracker.add(item)
    else:
        if item.split('/')[0] not in domain_tracker:
            final_url.append(item)
        else:
            remove_list.append(item)
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(final_url)
>>> ['dasdas.zz/alpha']

>>> print(remove_list)
>>> ['a.ru/11', 'a.ru/22', 'cc.com/31231', 'cc.com/312312412', 'cc.com/3123141241', 'cc.com/31231234232', 'dd.com/11', 'dd.com/22']
```